# Correlate two variables, with many (0,0) values?

Tags: correlation

Suppose you have a large but finite collection of tweets. You want to know whether talking about football tends to correlate with talking about basketball. You can generate a table for a few hundred users with x's of "NFL" mentions, and y's of "NBA" mentions for each user. Now consider the case where over half of them are (0,0). I actually have such tables for many word pairs: some graphs look like a messy y=mx, some look as if bounded by y=1/mx, some are one quadrant of a shotgun blast.

**Q: is there any mathematically sound way of describing the statistics, the correlations, when so many values are (0,0)?**

Intuitively speaking, I've run into two problems:

1) Using a simple linear correlation function in a spreadsheet, I seem to get similar correlation (r^2) values whether "I can tell" it's a shotgun or it's a y=1/x bounded system (i.e., exclusivity). I.d like a measure that distinguishes between exclusivity and no relation at all.

2) Sometimes I've generated graphs which look like y=1/x, and proves a case of exclusivity (such as sheep vs. goats) which I already believe to be true. Other times for very similar concepts, however, I see the same graph shape which implies exclusivity, a discrepancy that seems illogical (such as "football" vs. "NFL"), unless I've somehow discovered distinct populations that use different words to describe a similar interest. I'm wondering if what my intuitive response to these exclusivity graphs is ignoring hundreds of points squished at the origin : (1,1)'s.

**I hope for a statistical operation that would take my gut feel out of this analysis. Thanks**

Comment: How can something be bounded by $1/mx$ if you have (0,0) values?

Comment: Take for example, number of times someone voted Democratic vs. Republican. It is likely that the spread of points will be BOUNDED by y=1/x, as in most points hugging the two axes. Forgive if I used wrong term, but (0,0) is among the set of points fenced in by y=1/x.

Comment: Here are examples of the three cases. http://imgur.com/fYEGgcY
Perhaps I should start this over?  Consider how one of these plots has a point of (700,5),  "Mathematically", I would guess that this is similar to (700,0), so I wouldn't want to but this point in same bucket as the (1,1).  So I think bucketing isn't best approach.

Comment: Your figure helps understand things. The figures suggest that for a given x, (a) the mean of y is increasing linearly and (b) the variance is also increasing linearly.  This suggests you could use a poisson generalized linear model. The regression coefficients might match up with your intutions

Comment: Okay, great, can you point me to a primer on that? A way to find the mu, or ideally an Excel formula?

Comment: see http://www.indiana.edu/~jslsoc/files_research/xpost/xpost.pdf

Comment: Okay, you've been very helpful, but I think I will delete this question and start over with a refreshed focus, if that's okay.

Comment: Its best you not delete it. This serves as a nice archive for people looking for answers to similar questions later in time

Comment: Search for **null invariant** measures, like e.g. confidence

Answer (score 2):

Since there are so many zeros, have you considered ignoring the counts and just looking at conditional probabilities, i.e. the probability of a user mentioning NFL given they have NBA mentions?

$$
P(User_{NFL} | User_{NBA}) = \frac{P(User_{NFL} \cap User_{NBA})}{P(User_{NBA})}
$$

Depending on what you want to show, try looking one of these metrics

$$
\begin{align}
allConfidence(A,B) &= min \big\{P(A|B), P(B|A)\big\}\\  
maxConfidence(A,B) &= max \big\{P(A|B), P(B|A)\big\}\\
Kulczynski(A,B) &= \frac{1}{2}\big(P(A|B) + P(B|A) \big)\\
\end{align}
$$

I think maxConfidence might be what you're looking for but you can try all three and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a binary regression, logit or probit. You can use the difference in probability between two groups to assess the effect or association.